# Why must I be precise when selecting html elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm doing a tutorial which will result in a fancy html5/css3/js based calculator. Something that never happened to me before - I've tried to style the `operator` elements differently like that they can be easily distinguished from other keys like 0-9.

I've typed in my CSS `.keys .operator` and added a different background property. However, it didn't work.

Then I've tried to be more specific like `.keys span.operator`.

This worked. However, it have left me with question marks.

**My question:**

Why in this case I need to be so specific or else CSS doesn't swallow the background property?

Why I can't just type `.operator` class alone?

I thought that by typing `.keys .operator`, I select every html element with a class of `.operator` within any element that has a class of `.keys`.

That sounds logical to me but it didn't work.

If I would go with the train of thought imposed to me by force by CSS then theoretically I would need to be even more precise and write `div.keys span.operator` but in the tutorial it's not needed.

Can someone explain to me why?

Here's the code that I'm working on:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qgjyp

Comment: We'll need to see the html and css in the question.

Comment: I know but it would take too much space and not being able to be previewed here so I've decided to use codepen. Sorry if I made ppl confused.

Comment: Not all of it, just the relevant bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using more precision. The more 'precise' your CSS selector is, the more precedence it has over other CSS that is selecting the same element but with less precision.

You most likely have CSS below it that is overriding the CSS you provided or CSS that is more precise somewhere in your CSS file.

For example, `span` is less specific than `span.MyClass` so `span.MyClass` will take precedence over `span`. Any style with the `!important` attribute is an automatic win over anything, but should rarely be used.

Look over your CSS document or inspect it in the browser and see what classes are affecting that element.

Check out this link: [Specifics on CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: Thank you for your response :). I'm aware of this and checked my code but cannot really find any other elements using 'keys' with 'operator' class. Exactly in this combination. I thought that this already is very specific. Also I don't get why just selecting 'operator' class I can't style my little operation and evaluation keys. The code that I've presented in codepen is the entire code that I've typed while following the tutorial.

Comment: What color are you trying to use for the operator keys? They appear red for me.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use #FFF0F5 color and everything works when I type .keys span.operator but it doesn't work when i type just .keys .operator. I don't get it cause .operator already belongs to some of the span elements so styling either .operator itself or .keys .operator should work but it doesn't and I wish to know why

Comment: Can I have a hint on how to use developer tools from chrome to determine which class is affecting that element ? Or maybe you're using a specific plugin that is better than default developer tools from chrome ? :)

Comment: Option 1: Right click on the page and click `Inspect Element`. Option 2: `Ctrl+Shift+J` (or `Cmd+Opt+J` on Mac) to open the DevTools and bring focus to the Console.

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look, and if I remove the `span` in front of your `.operator`, it is fine for me. It might be an issue with your browser. I am using Chrome Canary. Here is a link to the pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGCfn

Comment: I'm using latest Google chrome in standard desktop mode over Windows 8.1. It work sto me too when I erase the 'span' elements before 'operator' class but why I can't just 'skip' the span element when selecting things to add parameters to ? An 'operator' class already is assigned to span element so selecting .keys .operator should do the trick right ? :)